# When converting an int to a hex, do we have to convert it to a string or can we keep it a type int? c++

Tags: c++

For this Systems I class that I'm in, they are wanting us to take in a number and convert it to hex. I know that I can do it this way:

```
cin >> std::hex >> x;
```

But for this program, I want to try and do it after, because of an `if` statement.

Here is the code that I have.

```
cout << "Enter an integer value between 0 and 255 for Green: ";
cin >> G;
if (G > 255 || G < 0)
{
    cout << "The number you have entered is bigger than 255 or smaller than 0.";
}
else 
{
    G = std::hex >> G;
}
```

Comment: hex is the input/output format and has nothing to do with the type

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. What exactly is the problem you're having with this code?

Comment: If by "hex" you mean printable hexadecimal characters, then a string is a good place to store them.

Comment: By "convert to hex" do you mean "format as hex"?  _Convert_ tends to mean manipulating the data itself which is not really necessary in your case.  Any `int` is sort of fundamentally base 2 at the hardware level because computers just store bits.  And an `int` is fundamentally just a single quantitative value at the C++ level (subject to range limitations as per the standard) and isn't a string yet at all.  Whereas _format_ talks about a creating a string representation of your value.

Comment: Nope, it's easier to convert from hex when reading. You can't have a "hex `int`", an `int` doesn't have a radix associated with it that you can change (you can consider the radix to be fixed as `2`).

Comment: Yes I meant format as hex.

Comment: `0x10` and `16` are precisely the same number, just with different *representation*. It's the same value. It doesn't matter if I write `0b10000` or `0x10`, I mean the same value. And the `int` doesn't care about representation, it stores value. Only once you want to create a representation (e.g. to print the number), it becomes important what base you choose for the number.

Comment: *"format as hex"* Means "convert int to a hex string", but you're doing the opposite thing?

Comment: As Wyck said, all numbers on a computer are stored in binary, i.e. 1101 0101, which is 213 in decimal or D5 in hex. Hex is just an easier way of reading binary, especially as the numbers get bigger. (Would you rather read 1001 1110 1110 1110 or just "9EEE"?) Either way, the important thing is these are all the same numbers just formatted differently. You're not trying to convert a number to hexadecimal, you're trying to *display* that number in hexadecimal.

Comment: `std::cout << std::hex << G;` basically does `std::cout.setbase(16); std::cout << G;`. `G = std::hex >> G;` just doesn't make sense: There's no operator `>>` that takes parameters of type `std::ios_base& (std::ios_base&)` and `int` (or whatever the type of `G` is). See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex and version `(8)` here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt

Comment: `cin >> std::hex >> x;` reads in a hex-formatted string and decodes its value into an integer. `cout << std::hex << x;` prints out an integer's value as a hex-formatted string.

Comment: What _exactly_ are you trying to accomplish? The code you posted is not consistent with its own commentary. You can always use `std::getline()` (or `>>`) to get a `std::string`, then use any number of C++ methods to parse it as either decimal or hexadecimal.

Answer (score 0):

> Take in a number and convert it to hex.

This satisfies the ask. Reads the decimal number (0 to 255), stores it in an integer. Uses the integer to display both decimal and hex formatting of the value entered.

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int G;

    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter an integer value between 0 and 255 for Green: ";
        std::cin >> G;
        if (G > 255 || G < 0)
        {
            std::cout << "The number you have entered is bigger" \
                << " than 255 or smaller than 0.\n";
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    std::cout<< "G is " << G << " in decimal and 0x" << std::hex << G << " in hex.\n";
}
```